# How to add silverlight project to ASP.NET project?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

I have a silverlight application project that I need to add to an ASP.NET Project. I know it can be done because you can choose to have both when you first create a silverlight project, i'm just not sure how you would do it after the fact. Any Ideas?

Comment: Are you looking to put it in the same *project* or same *solution*?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all Add a new website to your Silverlight application(if there are now ASP.NET website in your solution), by Right-clicking on the **ProjectSolution >Add>New Website**.

Now Rightclick on the ASP.NET website and Click Proporties.Now Click on the **Silverlight Applications** Tab. Now click on **Add** , and select **Use an existing Project** in the solution. Now You wil be able to see the Silverlight Applications name .Now Click on **Add** again to add the silverlight application to ASP.NET website.

After that , Set the ASP.NET website as Startup Project and ..TestPage.aspx as the Start Page.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the web application to your solution and go to your web project properties and under silverlight tab add your sl app